# Characters x through y in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that generates a random number which is then inserted between a string, similar to a password salt (but not really). This is my code:

```
    set passSalt to random number from 10000000 to 99999999
    do shell script "echo password | shasum -a 512"
    set passHash to result
    set cutHash1 to random number from 1 to 32
    set cutHash2 to random number from 33 to 64
    set cutHash3 to random number from 65 to 96
    set cutHash4 to random number from 97 to 128
    set combinedHash1 to characters cutHash1 through cutHash2 of passHash
    set combinedHash2 to characters cutHash3 through cutHash4 of passHash
    set finalHash to combinedHash1 and finalSalt and combinedHash2
```

What it does is generates a random number and inserts it between two random locations of the hashed version of *password.* At the last line, it returns

> Can’t make {"1", "9", "f", "9", "c", "c", "a", "a", "4", "d", "6", "b", "3", "7", "a", "6", "a", "2", "4", "3", "d", "b", "e", "0", "f", "2", "3", "1", "3", "7", "b", "1"} into type boolean.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change each "`and`" in the final line to "`&`". In Applescript, "`and`" is used to combine two Boolean values, while "`&`" is used for concatenation.

You will probably also want to return "`finalHash`" as text rather than a list:

```
set finalHash to (combinedHash1 & finalSalt & combinedHash2) as text
```

I presume you define "`finalSalt`" elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You're right about using `&`, not `and`, for concatenation. However, coercing lists of characters to text is bad practice: it's painfully inefficient and, more worringly, will return incorrect results if AS's `text item delimiters` property is anything other than an empty string. The right way to get a continuous text range is to use `text <start reference> through <end reference> of <text value>`, for example: `text (character cutHash1) through (character cutHash2) of passHash` which can be abbreviated to `text cutHash1 through cutHash2 of passHash` for convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though I figured it out myself a while after I posted this! :)